# Get-ADGroup members email address attribute

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have this code that pulls members of all distribution groups. I'm trying to get the member's email address to the same csv file as a new column instead of overwriting the DL data.

```
Get-ADGroup -Filter 'GroupCategory -eq "Distribution"' -Properties * | Select-Object name, mail, @{l='ManagedBy';e={$_.managedby -replace '^CN=|,.*$'}}, @{l='Members';e={$_.members -replace '^CN=|,.*$' -join ","}}, @{l='MemberOf';e={$_.memberOf -replace '^CN=|,.*$' -join ","}}  | Sort-Object Name, mail, ManagedBy, Members, MemberOf | export-csv DL.csv
import-csv -Path DL.csv | ForEach-Object {
  Get-ADUser -Filter {Members -like $_.members} -properties mail | Select-Object SamAccountName,Name,GivenName,mail
} | Export-csv -Path DL.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: You need to go through a two-step process: First, get the members of the group,  then, for each member, retrieve the member's email address (and any other attributes of the member you may be interested in) using `Get-ADUser`. You can't do it without both steps.

Comment: can get be added to the same csv file as export?

Comment: You may end up having to build your own objects and exporting them. Think your problem through, on paper if necessary, listing what information you want and where you can find it (from `Get-ADGroup` or `Get-ADUser`) and then looking at ways to put it all together. It may not be a one-liner even with efficient use of the pipe; not everything is.

Comment: You're right it can't be a one-liner which I don't mind. I guess as long as I get the end result. I've updated the code, however, I can't figure out how to export the data to the same csv file as a new column.